# How to avoid "null" values in a Json Object , when looping over it

Tags: javascript

I am learning vainilla JS (sorry in advance if I don't use some concepts properly), and while doing so, I am practising DOM manipulation and API fetching, with a free API i was given.

I have JSON with an structure similar to the one below, in which sometimes some fields get the value `null` ,or even change the structure of the attribute (as you can see in the 'Image Gallery' from the 3rd elelement.

I am looping through it to do different things, like creating a table, buidling some cards, and create an img gallery displaying the images from that element when clicking a button.
But whenever the loop finds the "null" value, it stops, and gives me a `Cannot read property 'length' of null`

The object is similar to this :

```
myObject = [
    {
        "field one": "something ",
        "Image Gallery": [
            {
                "src": "anImage.jpg",
                "title": "more text"
            },
            {
                "src": null,
                "title": "a title here"
            },
            {
                "src": "otherImg.jpg",
                "title": null
            }      
        ],
        "Management": null,
        "Scientific Name": "Urophycis tenuis",
        "Species Illustration Photo": {
            "src": null,
        },
        "last_update": "05/19/2021 - 13:04"
     },
    {
        "Habitat Impacts": "something ",
        "Image Gallery": null,
        "Management": 'some value',
        "Scientific Name": null,
        "Species Illustration Photo": {
            "src": 'img.jpg',
        },
        "last_update": "05/19/2021 - 13:04"
     },
    {
        "Habitat Impacts": "something ",
        "Image Gallery":  // Note that the Image gallery structure is an array here
            {
                "src": "anImage.jpg",
                "alt": "some text",
                "title": "more text"
            },     
        ,
         "Management": 'some value',
        "Scientific Name": "Urophycis tenuis",
        "Species Illustration Photo": {
            "src": 'img.jpg',
        },
        "last_update": "05/19/2021 - 13:04"
    }]
```

My Javascript code in which I get the error is :

```
function createCards(myObject) {
    let cardContainer = document.getElementById('cardContainer');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
            
        aInfoButtonLeft.onclick = function () {
            
            for (let x = 0; x < myObject[i]["Image Gallery"].length; x++) {   
                console.log(myObject[i]['Image Gallery'][x]["src"])
            }
        }
    }

}
```

How could I prevent the different "null" values to break the iteration, or to skip them and follow with the next value?
The only way I can think of is to write if conditions, but I would need one per every kind of attribute which might contain a Null

Comment: @RyDog  i tag you here, in case you have the time to help :)

Comment: @-mentioning users will not notify them *unless* the user has interacted with a post. Commenting/editing/etc. See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

Comment: ah, sorry, that user suggested me in another question, to tag him/her  ...thanks for the clarification, i am also learning to use this platform.

Comment: What is `aInfoButtonLeft`? You're looping over your array (not an object) and repeatedly adding a brand new event listener to it. And that makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While most languages with loops have the `break` statement, a good set of them also have the `continue` statement, including JavaScript. This allows you to easily "skip" the current iteration:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    console.log('A' + i);
    if (i%2 == 0) continue; // Only if a multiple of 2
    console.log('  B' + i);
}

> A1
>   B1
> A2
// no B2
> A3
>   B3
> A4
// no B4
```

For your first problem, being dealing with `null` values, you can simply check and continue. For your second problem, where the `"Image Gallery"` has a different structure at times, there are a few options:

1. Handle a single object and an array of objects differently
2. Convert a single object to an array of objects (with just that one object)

*also I'm assuming that your code comment "Note that the Image gallery structure is a string here" meant to say that it's an array.*

Showcasing both solutions at once, along with solving your first problem, we get something like this:

```js
function createCards(myObject) {
    let cardContainer = document.getElementById('cardContainer');

    for (let i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {

        let imgGallery = myObject[i]["Image Gallery"];

        // For the first problem, ignore null values
        if (imgGallery == null) continue;

        /* - - - Example of 1st solution to 2nd problem (begin) - - - */
        // Check whether imgGallery is an array (presumably of image objects)
        if (Array.isArray(imgGallery)) {
            // imgGallery is an array of images, iterate over it
            for (const img of imgGallery) {
                // handle img as an image
            }
        } else {
            // imgGallery is already an image object
            // handle imgGallery as an image
        }
        // The function would end here
        /* - - - Example of 1st solution to 2nd problem (end) - - - - */

        // 2nd solution for 2nd problem, we could force it to be an array
        if (!Array.isArray(imgGallery))
            imgGallery = [imgGallery];
        // so we can just use the original code, except we now use
        // the imgGallery variable of which we know it's an array
        aInfoButtonLeft.onclick = function () {
            for (let x = 0; x < imgGallery.length; x++) {
                // I noticed the .src can still be null, which we want to skip?
                // Mind that `continue`, just like `break`, works on the "closest" loop
                if (imgGallery[x].src == null) continue;
                console.log(imgGallery[x].src)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I noticed that image objects themselves can still have a `src` that's `null`. Adding another simple `(if src == null) continue;` check is all you need, as shown in the updated code above.

Comment: wow...just ...Thanks!!! ...what a instructive answer. 
I will check it carefully ..lots to learn there. 
Thanks a lot! 
And thanks for the Array-not-String comment..you are obviously right.

Answer (score 2):

- Try with an if statement. It will catch `null` and `undefined` objects:

  ```
    if (myObject[i]["Image Gallery"] != null) {
        for (let x = 0; x < myObject[i]["Image Gallery"].length; x++) {   
            console.log(myObject[i]['Image Gallery'][x]["src"])
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: cool..this is working so far with the Image Gallery values. 

Given that there are other attributes with that value, would it be a more general solution, or I should do the same whenever i loop over any attribute that might contain  a null? , Like, if later I want to get the values of "scientific Name" , for example

Comment: I guess you would need to check for every object you want to iterate. I don´t know any other solution. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

As posters above have mentioned, you'd need to check whether the value is null. You simply can't loop through an object that doesn't exist! So your choice would be not to use null objects in your structure -I'm not quite sure why you need them in the first place, maybe you could have a structure you loop through and another, placeholder structure - OR to check for null.

Comment: I am not the creator of that object. Is the object i get from the API, so I am supposed to work with it how it is.

Comment: I see. Well, in that case I don't see any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Onclick function should be outside of both of for loops.

p.s: Using the snippet makes things easier.

```js
var myObject = [{
    "field one": "something ",
    "Image Gallery": [{
        "src": "anImage.jpg",
        "title": "more text"
      },
      {
        "src": null,
        "title": "a title here"
      },
      {
        "src": "otherImg.jpg",
        "title": null
      }
    ],
    "Management": null,
    "Scientific Name": "Urophycis tenuis",
    "Species Illustration Photo": {
      "src": null,
    },
    "last_update": "05/19/2021 - 13:04"
  },
  {
    "Habitat Impacts": "something ",
    "Image Gallery": null,
    "Management": 'some value',
    "Scientific Name": null,
    "Species Illustration Photo": {
      "src": 'img.jpg',
    },
    "last_update": "05/19/2021 - 13:04"
  },
  {
    "Habitat Impacts": "something ",
    "Image Gallery": // Note that the Image gallery structure is a string here
    {
      "src": "anImage.jpg",
      "alt": "some text",
      "title": "more text"
    },
    "Management": 'some value',
    "Scientific Name": "Urophycis tenuis",
    "Species Illustration Photo": {
      "src": 'img.jpg',
    },
    "last_update": "05/19/2021 - 13:04"
  }
]

function createCards(myObject) {
  let cardContainer = document.getElementById('cardContainer');
  aInfoButtonLeft.onclick = function() {
  
    for (let i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
      if (myObject[i]["Image Gallery"]) {
        for (let x = 0; x < myObject[i]["Image Gallery"].length; x++) {
          console.log(myObject[i]['Image Gallery'][x]["src"])
        }
      }
    }
  }

}

createCards(myObject)
```

```html
<input id="aInfoButtonLeft" type="button" value="Button">
```